# How to add following static route address in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 to make it permanent?

Tags: networking, fedora, route

I have following list of route addresses which I need to add in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0` file in order to make it permanent add.

```
route add -net 101.122.122.0 netmask 255.255.248.0 gw 10.0.0.10
route add -net 132.138.109.3 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.0.0.10
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.10
route add -net 147.255.255.255 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.0.0.10
route add -net 102.128.172.2 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.0.0.10
```

In Windows it is simple to add. It can be achieved by adding just `-p` option with `route` command and it makes it permanent. What will be the file format for Linux.

Update:

`ifconfig` command does not list `eth0` interface.

`ip route show` gives following output:

```
default via 10.0.0.20 dev enp0s25  proto static  metric 100 
default via 10.0.0.20 dev wlp4s0  proto static  metric 600 
10.0.0.0/22 dev enp0s25  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.90  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/22 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.59  metric 600 
192.22.132.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.22.132.1 linkdown
```

Comment: As you add them to route-eth0 they are permanent. The will exist every time network interface is started/restarted. But why you add host as network?
 And why you do not use proper syntax for networks?

Comment: I many not be able to understand your question but I tried https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html with no luck.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route show` ?

Comment: @GAD3R question updated.